# Reading out value of specific key in array

Tags: php, arrays

I've made a multidimensional array for an event calendar. The question is HOW to address only the Startdate from this array.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 11
        [Title] => Evenement 1 van 1 dag
        [Startdate] => 2014-01-01
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 12
        [Title] => Evenement 2 van 1 week
        [Startdate] => 2014-02-01
    )
)
```

Can I load the Startdate to a variable?

Comment: `$arr[0]['Startdate']`? Most likely you want to [loop over the array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). To learn more about arrays, have a look at the [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Comment: You can, but it will be just one of them. `$star_date = $arr[0]['Stardate']`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's very easy:

```
$Startdate = $array[0]['Startdate'];
```

Where `$array` is the name of your array.

Change the number in the first set of square brackets to choose other StartDates in the multidimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_map:

```
$data = Array (...);

$getDate = function($arr) {
    return $arr['Startdate'];
}

$result = array_map($getDate, $data);
```

This gives you an array containing all start dates.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

A more generic approach:

```
$property = function($prop) {
    return function($obj) use ($prop) {
        return $obj[$prop];
    };
};

$result = array_map($property("StartDate"), $data);
// Basically, any time you need to map to a property of an object, you can use the $property function and pass the property you want to map to.
// need to get the titles instead?
$result = array_map($property("Title"), $data);
```